# Simple database embedded into Java app

Tags: java, database

I want to write simple java database driven application - with database build into app.
Everything within application - no remote connections or multiple users. Few tables, at most 10'000 rows each. Insert/update/delete operations, selects with joins and simple predicates. (`where name like 'A%' and create_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-06-30'`).

I will be grateful for any suggestions about engines I could use. I only programmed with external databases (MySQL, Oracle) which are too heavy for my needs in this project.

Comment: SQLLite, but it requires some native integration.  [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), pure Java SQL database, can run in single user/embedded mode

Comment: have you considered using sqlite? (sqlite4java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/) seems to be the best choice for u. It manages database in a single `.db` file. Just add the [SQLite jdbc driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) (`.jar`) in `classpath`. Even no installation of SQLite in ur system is needed.

**[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)** tutorial might help u.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

**What is Apache Derby?**

Apache Derby, an Apache DB subproject, is an open source relational database implemented entirely in Java and available under the Apache License, Version 2.0. Some key advantages include:

- Derby has a small footprint -- about 2.6 megabytes for the base engine and embedded JDBC driver.
- Derby is based on the Java, JDBC, and SQL standards.
- Derby provides an embedded JDBC driver that lets you embed Derby in any Java-based solution.
- Derby also supports the more familiar client/server mode with the Derby Network Client JDBC driver and Derby Network Server.
- Derby is easy to install, deploy, and use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Grails` which is very simple Java EE MVC ORM Framework.
You just need to set your domain classes which are the tables you need and thier fields, set the DB connection.

When you finished with that, you can run your application, Grails will decide if he needs to create your databse or not, and then you can make any SQL query that you want using Groovy and Grails.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things, why not take the JDK-bundled, Oracle-supported port of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)? Its small, has supported JDBC driver, allows transactions, ...

Lokk at [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) for a starting point.